# Databricks - transfer data from one databricks workspace to another

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

How can I transform my data in databricks workspace 1 (DBW1) and then push it (send/save the table) to another databricks workspace (DBW2)?

On the DBW1 I installed [this](https://databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download) JDBC driver.

Then I tried:

```py
(df.write
 .format("jdbc")
 .options(
   url="jdbc:spark://<DBW2-url>:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=<http-path-of-cluster>;AuthMech=3;UID=<uid>;PWD=<pat>",
   driver="com.simba.spark.jdbc.Driver",
   dbtable="default.fromDBW1"
 )
 .save()
)
```

However, when I run it I get:

```java
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][SparkJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
```

How to do this correctly?

Note: each DBW is in different subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view, the more scalable way would be to write directly into ADLS instead of using JDBC. But this needs to be done as following:

- You need to have a separate storage account for your data.  Anyway, use of DBFS Root for storage of the actual data [isn't recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#configuration-and-usage-recommendations) as it's not accessible from outside - that makes things, like, migration, more complicated.
- You need to have a way to access that storage account ([ADLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/) or [Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage)).  You can use access data directly (via `abfss://` or `wasbs://` URLs)
- In the target workspace you just create a table for your data written - so called [unmanaged table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/tables#--managed-and-unmanaged-tables). Just do (see [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html)):

```sql
create table <name>
using delta
location 'path_or_url_to data'
```

Comment: Yeah, this I consider more as a backup approach because of that 3rd step - you have to copy the data and then connect to the second workspace and run a notebook to actually create these tables - thats why I wanted to copy it directly via JDBC. What do you think?

Comment: You don’t have to copy anything.  Both workspaces can read the same files.

Comment: Agree with David - you just run `create table` once - I've added example

Comment: The intention was to transform the data in subscription A (with DBW1 and corresponding ADLS) and then push the transformed data into subscription B (with DBW2 and corresponding ADLS). With JDBC the database tables inside DBW2 would have been created straight away. When using your approach there is one more step - to actually create those database tables - exactly as your last step describes. And in order to be able to create the tables, I would need to create a notebook task for that (to be able to automatize it).

Comment: So I would need to 1. copy the data to ADLS and then 2. run the notebook task in DBW2 to create the tables.